# Check series of checkboxes according to string

Tags: javascript

I have group of checkboxes nearly equals to 100 all are with name checkbox1...checkbox1oo. I am getting a string from database in the bit format. Now I need to check checkboxes using for loop according to everyposition for string..

just taking example. String is 10010. that means I have to select checkbox 1st AND 4th. Hows it will be possible.

```
for (i=1;i<=5;i++)
{
check every position of sting==1
than document.formname.checkbox[i]==checked.
}
```

I wish to do something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get all the tags, loop through, get check boxes, build the string.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var str = "010101";
for(var i = 0; i< elements.length; i++) {
    if (elements[i].type == "checkbox") {
        var index = +(elements[i].name.match(/\d+/g)[0]); // get index

        elements[i].checked = !!(+str.charAt(index -1));
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UMuxP/

```
!!(+str.charAt(index -1))
```

could easily be:

```
str.charAt(index -1) === "1"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for( var i = 0, l = string.length ; i < l ; i++ ) {
    if( string.charAt(i) === "1" ) {
        document.forms[formname]['checkbox' + i].checked = true;
    }
}
```

where `string` is the string from your database, and `formname` is the id of the form you're manipulating

Comment: Probably needs to keep going for the full length of the checkbox collection to uncheck all remaining checkboxes that might have been checked when processing a previous string.

Comment: @user921300: You didn't quote the name of the form and a few other things. See corrections here: http://jsfiddle.net/UMuxP/7/

Comment: @RobG: Good point (although it's moot now, since Abstract's answer above has been accepted, so I'll leave my answer as-is)